# Waiting for all functions to return before returning value

Tags: python, python-2.7, asynchronous

Imagine I have a function like:

```
def func1():
    return int(requests.get('https://www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min=0&max=10&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new').text)
```

and I want to call this function three times, sum the responses and then return the sum squared or something simple.  How can I do this so the three function calls are asynchronous but it waits for them all to return, a la Promise.all in Javascript?

I am using Python 2.

Comment: Why not threads?

Comment: If you were using Python 3, you could use its async features... In Python 2, you have to make do with [threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use threading for that, the easiest would be via the `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` package (don't let it fool you, it's not multiprocessing despite being in the package):

```
import requests
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

# let's make it a bit more flexible
RANDOM_URL = 'https://www.random.org/integers/'
RANDOM_PARAMS = {"num": 1, "min": 0, "max": 10, "col": 1, "base": 10,
                 "format": "plain", "rnd": "new"}

def func1(*args):  # args added to account for the dummy payload from pool.map
    return int(requests.get(RANDOM_URL, params=RANDOM_PARAMS).text)

pool = ThreadPool(processes=3)
response_sum = sum(pool.map(func1, range(3)))
print("Squared response: {}".format(response_sum**2))
```

Comment: Just curious, are there any performance differences between my answer and yours? Would multithreading be more efficient or multiprocessing in this IO bound use-case?

Comment: @SamChats - as I've stated, while `ThreadPool` is in the `multiprocessing.pool` package it doesn't use multiprocessing at all - it's just a convenience wrapper around ye olde `threading` structures so you don't have to map your data to the threads yourself or deal on how to retrieve it back once your threads finish processing. The main purpose for it is to be used as mock `multiprocessing.Pool` mostly for testing/debugging reasons, but it's very useful for cases like this.

Comment: Cool. Is this remotely related to the `Queue` structure?

Comment: In this case - not even in the slightest.

Answer (score 1):

For your purposes, I'm modifying the function a bit:

```
def func1():
    page = requests.get('https://www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min=0&max=10&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new').text
    num = extract_num(page) # Any parsing function that extracts the number and converts it to an integer type.
    cumulative += num # Sums up
```

Then, use threads:

```
import threading

cumulative = 0

for i in range(3): # Gets random numbers asynchronously.
    threading.Thread(target=func1).start()
print cumulative
```

Comment: I see what you did there with a global variable, but I just included the random numbers as an example of a request that could take variable time, I'm not specifically concerned with summing random numbers

Comment: You should deal with joining your threads back to the main thread before printing the `cumulative` result. You should also use a mutex for that `cumulative` variable as `cumulative += num` is not an atomic operation. To see the issue, replace `num` in `func1()` with a fixed number (say 10) and loop the whole thing 20 times then see what it prints. Plus `cumulative` would have to be defined as global for this to work.

Comment: @Rob Oh! But threads as defined above can handle variable time. Won't they do what you want?

Comment: @zwer Hmmm... I thought `join()` is only necessary if there is no operation to be done after initialising the threads... But there's a `print` out there so I didn't use `join()`.

Comment: The issue is that standard Python augmented assignment `+=` isn't an atomic operation, so you can't guarantee that `cumulative += num` will behave correctly: multiple threads might try to update `cumulative` at the same time, so you need a way to stop one thread from reading its value when another thread is just about to write to it.

Comment: `join()` is necessary to make sure your threads have finished processing before you use the results from them (like printing in this case). A mutex (`threading.Lock` would suffice here) is necessary to ensure only one thread is modifying `cumulative` at one time so that an addition from one thread doesn't overwrite the addition from another. `global cumulative` is required so that `func1()` would actually modify the global `cumulative` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your taste, and if you're okay with installing a 3rd party backport module https://pypi.python.org/pypi/futures you could also use `concurrent.futures` as a higher level interface to avoid dealing with threads and having an API more alike to the promises/futures you mentioned in your question:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import requests

def func1():
    return int(requests.get('https://www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min=0&max=10&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new').text)

ex = ThreadPoolExecutor()
f1 = ex.submit(func1)
f2 = ex.submit(func1)
f3 = ex.submit(func1)

print(f1.result(), f2.result(), f3.result())
```

Comment: To quote the OP "I am using Python 2.", and it's also there in the tags of the question. `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` is not available in Python 2.

Comment: I thought it was standard in 2 as well, sorry. As it turns out you have to install a backport module to get it in python 2 https://pypi.python.org/pypi/futures